# How do I capture data from a single cell in `DataGridView`

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to get the value from the `ID` field in a `DataGridView`.  I had the `Column` labeled Contact_ID set to `visible = false` and working fine, I could get the data from the column.

Today I am getting an error message `Unhandled acceptation of type` and a message `Column named Contact_ID cannot be found`

I have made the `Contact_ID visible = true` and the width of the column = 2 so that you cant really see it

Here is the 2 lines of code that I am using.  The `row` index is being captured just fine.

```
DataGridViewRow row = customer_ContactsDataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningRow;
string contact_ID = row.Cells["Contact_ID"].Value.ToString();
```

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: try to use index, like Cells[0] and see if it works. Rgds,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help from Alex Bell, here are the lines of code that I ended up with.

```
DataGridViewRow row = customer_ContactsDataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningRow;
string contact_ID = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

it is easier to get the data by using it's numeric `cell` location in a `DataGridView`